# Signal handler in XS module

Tags: perl, signals, perl-xs

I have very simple constructor and destructor for some C-based library. Well, i need to catch signals like TERM and others to enforce destructor calling on perl's mandatory death with `killall perl` e.g.
In fact i need local $SIG{**TERM**} for each object to be installed, written inside XS constructor. Is it possible?
!thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. A signal is sent to and trapped by a process, not objects.

Another approach might be to maintain a global list of all the objects that must be cleaned up, and install a single signal handler that will clean up each object on that list.

Comment: Thanks. It is clear for me. I'll try to create a global array of all active objects in my .pm to clean them up after signal.

Comment: The question is how to create a signal handler inside MyModule.xs, because I want to keep this clean up array inside this module